# swift parse json - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

Here is struct codable code:

```
import Foundation

public struct TaskID: Codable {
    let embedded: Embedded
}

public struct Embedded: Codable {
    let task: [Task]
}

public struct Task : Codable {

    let embedded: EmbeddedVariable
    let id : String
    let name: String
    let assignee: String
    let created: String
    let processDefinitionId: String
}

public struct EmbeddedVariable: Codable {

    let variable : [Variables]
}

public struct Variables: Codable {

    let value : String
    let name: String
}
```

I have tried by codingKey and also tried using _embedded too. Face same issue.

**Error log:** Response could not be decoded because of error:

```
 Alamofire.AFError.
 ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))
```

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Here is the code for JSONSerialization:

```
      // MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try K.ProductionServer.baseURL.asURL()
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    print(urlRequest)
    // HTTP Method
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
   
    let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
    let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + (authToken ?? "")
    print("baearer token::\(bearerToken)")
    
    // Common Headers
    urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.acceptType.rawValue)
    urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)
    urlRequest.setValue(bearerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.authentication.rawValue)
    
    // Parameters
    if let parameters = parameters {
        do {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }
    }
    
    return urlRequest
}
```

Here is the code json return response:

```
   import Foundation
  import Alamofire

public class APIClient {
@discardableResult
private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (AFResult<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {
            
    return AF.request(route)
                    .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
                        completion(response.result)
                        print("framework response::",response.result)
    }
}

public static func taskID(id: String, completion:@escaping (AFResult<MyTaskData>)->Void) {
    
    performRequest(route: APIRouter.TaskById(id: id), completion: completion)
}


}//APIClient
```

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, print always `error`. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Two people have posted answers about an extra comma, can you verify that this is the issue or if it is a mistake when editing the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, it was my mistake..

Comment: @vadian i have added error log can you check it out

Comment: The error says you are decoding `Task.self` rather than (required) `TaskID.self` but there are still other errors. How do you handle the leading underscore character of the keys?

Comment: The only issue with the provided code is `_embedded`. Maybe your issue is inside `MyTaskData`. Please post a complete demo of request and response.

Comment: Is there any update on this question ?

Answer (score 6):

In your JSON payload,There is a extra comma at end of the value for key **processDefinitionId**.

Try this JSON Formatter tool to validate the JSON: [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

```
"task":[
        {
         //...

         "id": "412a2aca-06ae-11ea-8860-120ef5ab2c25",
         "name": "Quick Evaluation",
         "assignee": "demo",
         "created": "2019-11-14T07:13:27.558+0000",
         "processDefinitionId": "quickEvaluation:1:129ce2b1-0616-11ea-8860-120ef5ab2c25", // remove this coma(,) from this line

        }
```

**Update:**

Use `CodingKey` for the `_embedded`. Try the following way

```
// MARK: - TaskID
struct TaskID: Codable {
    let embedded: Embedded
    let count: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case count
    }
}

// MARK: - Embedded
struct Embedded: Codable {
    let task: [Task]
}

// MARK: - Task
struct Task: Codable {
    let embedded: EmbeddedVariable
    let id, name, assignee, created: String
    let processDefinitionID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case id, name, assignee, created
        case processDefinitionID = "processDefinitionId"
    }
}

// MARK: - EmbeddedVariable
struct EmbeddedVariable: Codable {
    let variable: [Variable]
}

// MARK: - Variable
struct Variable: Codable {
    let links: Links
    let name, value, type: String
    let valueInfo: ValueInfo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case links = "_links"
        case name, value, type, valueInfo
    }
}

// MARK: - Links
struct Links: Codable {
    let linksSelf: SelfClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
    }
}

// MARK: - SelfClass
struct SelfClass: Codable {
    let href: String
}

// MARK: - ValueInfo
struct ValueInfo: Codable {
}
```

Comment: still facing same error Response could not be decoded because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
framework response:: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))

Comment: here is my full json response data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rwl0KHbWHpq7c6x274M6dX9o1hpDGSL5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rwl0KHbWHpq7c6x274M6dX9o1hpDGSL5/view?usp=sharing use this

Comment: gaved drive url access

Comment: in your JSON response, there is no value in any `variable[]`. so i recommend you try by removing your `EmbeddedVariable`.

Answer (score 4):

How about changing all `embeded` to `_embeded` in codable struct?

In your `APIClient` class, `JSONDecoder` instance created with default. and it doesn't change key names during decoding **include underscore**.

> The `JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.useDefaultKeys` strategy is the strategy used if you don't specify one. [Documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/usedefaultkeys)

#### Code

```swift
public struct TaskID: Codable {
    let _embedded: Embedded
}

public struct Task : Codable {

    let _embedded: EmbeddedVariable
    let id : String
    let name: String
    let assignee: String
    let created: String
    let processDefinitionId: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. i found answer, its because of header accept type. From backend they are using accept - application/hal+json. here i have used application/json. how can i use application/hal+json based on my code. specifically for particular post method alone they are using application/hal+json remaining application/json are used.

Answer (score 3):

try use QuickType.io

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let embedded: WelcomeEmbedded
    let count: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case count
    }
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseWelcomeEmbedded { response in
>      if let welcomeEmbedded = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - WelcomeEmbedded
struct WelcomeEmbedded: Codable {
    let task: [Task]
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseTask { response in
>      if let task = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - Task
struct Task: Codable {
    let embedded: TaskEmbedded
    let id, name, assignee, created: String
    let processDefinitionID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case id, name, assignee, created
        case processDefinitionID = "processDefinitionId"
    }
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseTaskEmbedded { response in
>      if let taskEmbedded = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - TaskEmbedded
struct TaskEmbedded: Codable {
    let variable: [Variable]
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseVariable { response in
>      if let variable = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - Variable
struct Variable: Codable {
    let links: Links
    let embedded: JSONNull?
    let name, value, type: String
    let valueInfo: ValueInfo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case links = "_links"
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case name, value, type, valueInfo
    }
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseLinks { response in
>      if let links = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - Links
struct Links: Codable {
    let linksSelf: SelfClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
    }
}
```

> ```
> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseSelfClass { response in
>      if let selfClass = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - SelfClass
struct SelfClass: Codable {
    let href: String
}
```

> To parse values from Alamofire responses:
>
> ```
>    Alamofire.request(url).responseValueInfo { response in
>      if let valueInfo = response.result.value {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
> ```

```
// MARK: - ValueInfo
struct ValueInfo: Codable {
}

// MARK: - Helper functions for creating encoders and decoders

func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}

// MARK: - Alamofire response handlers

extension DataRequest {
    fileprivate func decodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {
        return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))
            }

            return Result { try newJSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) }
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    fileprivate func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: decodableResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func responseWelcome(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Welcome>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return responseDecodable(queue: queue, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. i found answer, its because of header accept type. From backend they are using accept - application/hal+json. here i have used application/json. how can i use application/hal+json based on my code. specifically for particular post method alone they are using application/hal+json remaining application/json are used.

Comment: if your are using urlRequest :
urlRequest.addValue("application/hal+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
Alamofire:
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
  "Content-Type": "application/hal+json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?term=smh", headers: headers)
  .responseJSON { response in
  debugPrint(response)
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic Alamofire request.
There should be no error if you use the following structure parsing json.

```
    Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let jsonData = value as! NSDictionary
            completionHandler(jsonData, nil)
            print("****** JSON \(jsonData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
```

Here I have placed it inside of your code. 
You should try the headers like I have shown below. 
You need to fill in your appropriate headers.

```
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try K.ProductionServer.baseURL.asURL()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    print(urlRequest)
    // HTTP Method
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
    let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + (authToken ?? "")
    print("baearer token::\(bearerToken)")

    // Common Headers
    //urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: 
    //HTTPHeaderField.acceptType.rawValue)
    //urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: 
    //HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)
    //urlRequest.setValue(bearerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: 
    //HTTPHeaderField.authentication.rawValue)

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + currentToken
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let jsonData = value as! NSDictionary
            completionHandler(jsonData, nil)
            print("****** JSON \(jsonData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }

//return urlRequest
}
```

Hope This helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. i found answer, its because of header accept type. From backend they are using accept - application/hal+json. here i have used application/json. how can i use application/hal+json based on my code. specifically for particular post method alone they are using application/hal+json remaining application/json are used.

Comment: Where it says in my answers (inside the headers) set the value of content-type to application/hal+JSON